# Group my dataframe by values in one column?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

How can I group my dataframe based on the values in one column?

Input is:

```
ID     Name     Revenue     Cluster
1234   John     123         1
1235   Jane     761         2
1237   Mary     276         3
1297   Paul     439         2
1376   Peter    254         1
1425   David    532         3
```

Expected output is:

```
Cluster 1                  Cluster 2               Cluster 3
ID     Name     Revenue    ID    Name   Revenue    ID     Name   Revenue
1234   John     123        1235  Jane   761        1237   Mary   276
1376   Peter    254        1297  Paul   439        1425   David  532
```

Is there a way to do this using `.groupby`? I have played around with it but can't seem to get the format I require. Is there a better/simpler way?

Comment: Group by which value? What column? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried ```df.groupby(['Cluster'],as_index=False)['ID','Name','Revenue']```, but all it came out was a df with just ID,Name and Revenue, the Cluster column had disappeared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for counter, then reshape by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html), change order in `MultiIndex` in columns of level, sorting it and last add `Cluster` values:

```
df = (df.set_index([df.groupby('Cluster').cumcount(), 'Cluster'])
        .unstack()
        .swaplevel(1,0, axis=1)
        .sort_index(axis=1)
        .rename(columns=lambda x: f'Cluster {x}', level=0))
print (df)
Cluster Cluster 1                Cluster 2               Cluster 3         \
               ID   Name Revenue        ID  Name Revenue        ID   Name   
0            1234   John     123      1235  Jane     761      1237   Mary   
1            1376  Peter     254      1297  Paul     439      1425  David   

Cluster          
        Revenue  
0           276  
1           532
```

Comment: Maybe an explanation of your code would be helpful for the OP. Like this, he will just copy-paste.